# Why has my XSLT style suddenly stopped parsing the Product Advertising API XML response?

Tags: xml, xslt, amazon-web-services, xml-parsing, amazon-product-api

Can anyone tell me why this xslt file is not parsing the sample xml file I've attached?  It has been working for a couple of years but it has suddenly stopped.  Without the stylesheet the xml file returns from Amazon ok but I can't style it now.

The xslt file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><!-- DWXMLSource="wii top sellers Med.xml" -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:aws="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2005-10-05">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xml>
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="aws:ItemSearchResponse/aws:Items/aws:Item" />
    </root>
    </xml>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="aws:Item">
<xsl:variable name="asin" select="aws:ASIN" />

    <Item>
        <gameAsin>
            <xsl:value-of select="$asin" />
        </gameAsin>
    </Item>
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The sample of the XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ItemSearchResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01">
<OperationRequest>
        <RequestId>3dadfcef-c438-40bd-b96b-1ba34811aa70</RequestId>
        <Arguments>
            <Argument Name="Operation" Value="ItemSearch"></Argument>
            <Argument Name="Service" Value="AWSECommerceService"></Argument>
            <Argument Name="AssociateTag" Value="wii07-21"></Argument>
            <Argument Name="Keywords" Value="&quot;Bundle&quot;"></Argument>
            <Argument Name="Sort" Value="salesrank"></Argument>
            <Argument Name="SubscriptionId" Value="xxxxxxxxx"></Argument>
            <Argument Name="ItemSearch.1.BrowseNode" Value="676410011"></Argument>
            <Argument Name="Signature" Value="xxxxxxxx"></Argument>
            <Argument Name="ItemSearch.Shared.SearchIndex" Value="VideoGames"></Argument>
        <Argument Name="Timestamp" Value="2012-03-01T15:44:24Z"></Argument>
            <Argument Name="ResponseGroup" Value="Large"></Argument>
            <Argument Name="ItemSearch.2.BrowseNode" Value="676398011"></Argument>
        </Arguments>
        <RequestProcessingTime>0.2811460000000000</RequestProcessingTime>
</OperationRequest>
<Items>
    <Item>
        <ASIN>B004JMZH4O</ASIN>
    </Item>
</Items>
</ItemSearchResponse>
```

Any help appreciated as 5 of my sites have stopped working because of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Update

It turned out that, besides the XML namespace issue addressed below, there has been another problem involved, which both amounted to the problems at hand, see Mark's closing comment:

> Amazon has changed the Endpoint from xml-uk.amznxslt.com to
>   'ecs.amazonaws.co.uk'.

---

<strike>Presumably the</strike> The [XML namespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace) of the [Amazon Product Advertising API](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/Welcome.html) has been updated (as confirmed via the current [Schema Location](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/SchemaLocation.html)), see the respective statements:

#### XSLT transform

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:aws="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2005-10-05">
```

#### XML response

```
<ItemSearchResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01">
```

### Cause

The namespaces do not match anymore, consequently the respective selectors in the XML transform (e.g. `select="aws:ItemSearchResponse/aws:Items/aws:Item"`) won't match the elements from the XML response.

### Solution

Updating the namespace in your transform will <strike>likely</strike> remedy the issue, assuming Amazon has just added elements etc. - the elements you are actually using in the transform (`aws:Item` and `aws:ASIN`) are still present at least; <strike>otherwise you might need to adjust the selectors according to the new schema in turn.</strike>

---

#### Appendix

To illustrate my comment - this is the result I get from applying the transform with the adjusted namespace, which applies to all result elements accordingly as well now and might affect your subsequent processing pipeline accordingly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xml xmlns:aws="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01">
  <root>
    <Item>
      <gameAsin>B004JMZH4O</gameAsin>
    </Item>
  </root>
</xml>
```

Comment: Hi Steffen, thanks for your help.  I've changed the date in the line of the xslt file but still no joy.  The elements are still correct as I've gone through the xml file to check.  One thing that is odd is that the 21011-08-01 date is returned if there is NO xslt specified in the call to amazon but if it IS specified (with the correct 2011 date) the file has nothing in it except the xlmns:aws but with the 2005 date despite it being changed in the xslt file!?? It's as is it's reading from a different xslt file.

Comment: @Mark_54: I've just verified that the fix works for me indeed (i.e. no item returned with the files you provided and one item returned after I adjusted the namespace) - maybe you have an accidental change in place now due to your debugging attempts (see my edit of your question or the date typo in your preceding comment for example)?

Comment: Ok Steffen.  I really appreciate you spending time helping me here.  I'm not an expert at xml/xslt so I predict me taking some time to sort this.  Can you post what exact correction to made?  Was it just the date?  I've gone on to the AWS site to copy the correct line but still no joy.  I must be really thick!

Comment: @Mark_54: I just replaced the XML namespace declaration in your XSLT transform (`xmlns:aws="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2005-10-05"`) with the one in the provided XML response (`xmlns:aws="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01"`), i.e. just `2005-10-05` with `2011-08-01` in fact.

Comment: Steffen - that's exactly what I did (and have tried again) with no joy.  I'm in the UK so do you know if the schema is a different version here?

Comment: @Mark_54: Maybe this affects your subsequent processing pipeline as well, i.e. the transform yields a XML response with the very same namespace change of course, so depending on how you extract the items in turn, you might hit the very same issue, see my updated answer for an illustration.

Comment: Steffen this is what is returned when the style sheet is applied -  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xml xmlns:aws="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2005-10-05">
  <root />
</xml>

Comment: @Mark_54: This clearly indicates that you are still using your original XSLT transform by some means, insofar this is the only source where the now outdated `2005-10-05` namespace can stem from - you must have done a mistake somewhere, either by not updating the correct XSLT file in the first place (e.g. a local copy only) or not using the correct XSLT file in turn (e.g. not replacing the one in use in your server with the modified one). The latter might actually be caused by caching eventually, i.e. depending on how you do the XSLT processing, you might need to restart your (web) server.

Comment: Steffen - I've made some progress.  I've opened the xml file with the xslt file embedded in it and it displays the ASIN but with no element tiles only the ASIN number when viewed in a browser.  Is there must be some problem with how the call to AWS is made and how the xslt is applied (It's added to the call by adding '&Style=http://www.wiiuser.co.uk/bundles.xslt' to it)  This has worked ok for years and nothing has changed??  I can post the line of code up to see if you can spot a mistake in it.  I totally understand if you don't want to carry on helping if you're busy. Let me know .

Comment: @Mark_54: If you post your code, please add it as an update at the end of your answer to ease reading and follow up (no guarantees that I'll be able to though indeed ;)

Comment: Hi Steffen, sorry I've had to help my kids to their homework!  Am I able to add the files as attachemtns?  There are two: one that calls AWS and the xslt file.

Comment: @Mark_54: Ah, I see - no, attachments are not available, and posting huge code fragments isn't ideal either, thought you meant _line(s) of code_ literally in the sense of 'a few' ;) Do you have any option to make them available to me out of band?

Comment: Steffen.  I can't work out how to post the code to get it to appear correctly so please forgive me for posting it inline.  This is the call to AWS.  The xslt is as I posted originally.       Dim RESTstring6 ="http://xml-uk.amznxslt.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&AssociateTag=wii07-21&SubscriptionId=116AQMJ35GESH5XBF1G2&Operation=ItemSearch&ItemSearch.Shared.SearchIndex=VideoGames&ItemSearch.1.BrowseNode=676410011&ItemSearch.2.BrowseNode=676398011&Sort=salesrank&Keywords=%22Bundle%22&ResponseGroup=Large&Style=http://www.wiiuser.co.uk/bundles.xslt

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8417/discussion-between-steffen-opel-and-mark-54)

Comment: This comment thread has derailed from the topic at hand. Please take it to chat and/or edit the pertinent details into the question or answer, or possibly even ask a new question.

Comment: Steffen, before you waste your time going through the code  - I've just re run everything (after my long break) to test it all again and, without changing anything, it seems to work!!????  I think it might be something to do with the way FF caches but I'll test everything again and let you know how it goes

Comment: Steffen - I've found the problem.  Amazon has changed the Endpoint from xml-uk.amznxslt.com to 'ecs.amazonaws.co.uk'.  This, together with the date change you suggested has cleared all the problems.  Once again, thank you very much for all your help.